# Landscape mode not working with no keyboard in AVD?

Tags: android-emulator, landscape

I've created two AVDs, one with hardware keyboard, and other without..the one with keyboard shows the landscape mode in the android screen when I click CTRL + F11/F12 or 7/9 on numpad, but in the AVD with no hardware keyboard, the hardware things all change orientation, like the first AVD, but the android screen stays and doesn't change orientation to landscape, like this: http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/3624/landscapeh.jpg

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the 2.3 AVD and it is already answered here

[Android - Emulator in landscape mode, screen does not rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394447/android-emulator-in-landscape-mode-screen-does-not-rotate)

Answer (score 1):

1. Run 'Android SDK and AVD Manager'
2. Select AVD
3. Edit
4. check Keyboard lid support
   if value is no, set to yes.
5. Run AVD and try

Good luck!!

Comment: What's the difference between that and 'keyboard support'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an API 19 (Android 4.4.2). I had wanted to *only* support running in Landscape mode. Despite setting Orientation to Portrait when editing the device (under Startup size and orientation), the device would always start Portrait.

I ended up manually switching the width and height in the `hardware-qemui.ini` file.

So, edit this file in a text editor:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<deviceName>.avd\hardware-qemu.ini
```

Switch the values of the width and height, so that the width is longer than the height:

```
hw.lcd.width = 800
hw.lcd.height = 480
```

The AVD now boots in Landscape mode. The orientation may still be changed with shortcut keys.