# Android emulator on 2.3.3 (level 10) won't rotate display with hw keyboard disabled

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

So as the title says, on an AVD with android 2.3.3, if the hw keyboard is set to false the displays stops rotating when you rotate the AVD with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

I tried the solution that somebody mentioned at [Android - Emulator in landscape mode, screen does not rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394447/android-emulator-in-landscape-mode-screen-does-not-rotate) with the accelerometer setting and the keyboard lid setting but it didn't work.

Is there a (easy?) way to get it to work without resorting to AVD with 2.2?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried numlock keys `7`/`9` (with NumLock off)?

Comment: Just tried again to make sure, same as with the F's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

Its a bug :D