# How to rotate screen inside AVD with Android Emulator (Not the AVD rotation)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Emulator with Android 4.4.2 API level 19 Skin WVGA800 and when I press `Left Ctrol+F11`, AVD disposition changes from Portait to Landscape but screen orientation inside AVD still being Portrait. I appreciate any help!!

Comment: It's a bug with the 4.4 emulator.

Comment: There is no way to solve it?

Comment: As far as I know, the only emulator that works well in both orientations (changes from portrait to lanscape and vice versa) is the 2.2 emulator.

Comment: Try using a Genymotion emulator. it is wayyyy faster and doesn't have this rotation bug (there's even webcam support)

http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Try pressing key `9` in the number keyboard.. @RenierRuizRivera

Comment: Thanks @Rperryng, i'm trying genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I found this app "Set Orientation" that allows you to force your device into a particular screen orientation. Supports all orientations, which on Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) and above includes reverse (upside-down) and sensor-based orientations.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation&rdid=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation

I hope this help people with the same problem. It was useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug on emulator. API level 19 (4.4) not support screen orientation:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671

Try change the API level target on your AVD settings. API level 18 (4.3) works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

[This so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394447/android-emulator-in-landscape-mode-screen-does-not-rotate) provides some way to fix this bug in the emulator like:

1- disabling the "Hardware keyboard present" checkbox in the "Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD)" window.

2- removing the "Keyboard lid support" option in the settings of the hardwere virtual machine

3- setting accelerometer property of the emulator set to True.

OR Problem are not solve , try this....
  Num Lock is "OFF" & Press (Keypad 7 or Keypad 9)

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug still in emulator running API 27. What worked for me:
Advanced Settings -> Keyboard -> Enable keyboard input (disable)