# How to change portrait to landscape in android emulator in windows

Tags: android, orientation

I have big doubt in android , How to change into the landscape mode. I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. The orientation of screen is only changing not the content of the screen.
So what to do.....

Comment: Are you sure screen rotation is turned on in the settings?

Comment: yes it is turned on...

Comment: Post your manifest please

Answer (score 1):

Press 9 in your numpad. Might work. Or you can change the orientation in the app. Add this to your manifest:

```
android:orientation = "landscape"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure screen rotation is turned on in settings and the application in the view is rotate-able

[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9972266/435706)

delete the device and create it again, it may help

Comment: Have you checked the link @RagniTamrakar ?