# Phonegap Android don't rotate

Tags: android, cordova, rotation, landscape

I know that with CTRL+MAC+F11 I can rotate de AVD (and is rotating) but THE APP isn't rotating. I've found a lot of post that ask "how to lock the rotation", but **I want it to rotate!**

My Manifest was:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1"      android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.overloadsoft.storydo" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop" 
        android:name="StoryDo" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

and I tried to add

```
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

and some variations, but didn't work...

ADDED:
The Target is Android 4.4.2 API Level 19
The "Hardware Keyboard present" is UNCHECKED
Skin with Dynamics hardware control
CPU/ABI: Intel atom x86 (With Intel Acceleretor)

Comment: Is it Android 4.4? [This MIGHT be relevant](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671)

Comment: Likewise if you are testing on the "L" Developer Preview emulator, as it has the same emulator bug.

Comment: Thanx for answering! I added more info, its 4.4.2 (but not L)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.3 and 4.4 emulators have a rotation bug, as does the new Android L Developer Preview.

[image]

This image is from 2.3. [Here is the issue tracker for 4.4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671) and [for 2.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189) and [Android L](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34237) with Google.

> **STEPS TO REPRODUCE**:
>
> 1. Create an Android 4.4 ARM emulator image
> 2. Open an app (e.g., Messaging)
> 3. Press - to rotate the screen

---

Alternatively [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394447/android-emulator-in-landscape-mode-screen-does-not-rotate):

> In my case it was solved by disabling the `"Hardware keyboard present"` checkbox in the `"Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD)"` window.

---

From the Google Thread for Android L:

> With the Android L emulator you can go into landscape by opening your app, then opening the camera app (you will need to set an emulated camera in AVD) record a video. Then press ctr-f12 of 11. In the camera app click the video thumbnail and play it back. The video should go to landscape. Then press the multitasking button and multitask into your app. DO NOT GO TO THE HOME SCREEN OR YOU WILL HAVE TO GO INTO THE CAMERA APP, GO TO LANDSCAPE AND REPLAY THE VIDEO! please let me know if this works for any other android emulator versions.

Comment: I have the "Hardware Keyboard Present" unchecked already... another suggestion?

Comment: I read the "bug" link and it seems that it's a big issue... it's good to know I am not alone! hahahaha