# How to Set landscape orientation for tablet?

Tags: flutter, widget

i am trying to set landscape orientation for the tablet after running my app, always running in portrait mode, here is what I did:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Set landscape orientation
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the orientation is not working on **Nexus 9 API R emulator** tablet, but it works fine on **Pixel C API R emulator** and **Nexus 7 2012 API R** tablet

Answer (score 0):

Add This Type before materialApp

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
        return MaterialApp();
```

Comment: Then close your app and restart your app again.

This is work for me brother

Comment: yes, i did that also, it works on the phone, but not on the tablet

Answer (score 0):

There are two situations,

1. Set the orientation for the entire app and never let the user change the orientation.- you have to set `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in the FlutterActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Set the orientation to the landscape at first and change as the user wants.-

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight])
```

will go into the Main AppState Management class.

Comment: Thank, i did that but it is not working on Nexus 9 API R emulator tablet

Comment: look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394447/android-emulator-in-landscape-mode-screen-does-not-rotate)